# Error al agregar elemento a la pila

Tags: c, struct

Tengo una estructura `Pila` que guarda estructuras de tipo `CD`, pero a la hora de agregar un CD a la Pila se crashea el programa.

Por lo que veo es en el momento de agregar un CD a la pila, no sé si esta bien mi código. Uso punteros. La función recibe un puntero que apunta a una `Pila`, y otro que apunta a un `CD`.

He modificado varias cosas pero no resuelven mi problema.

#### CÓDIGO:

```
typedef struct{ 
    char titulo[50];
    char autor[50];
    float duracion;
    int numeroCan;
}CD;

typedef struct{
    int top;
    CD cds[tamanio];
}Pila;

//Funcion para agregar un CD a la pila
void Push(Pila *ptrPila, CD *ptrCD){
    if(Full(ptrPila)){ //Verifica si la pila está llena

        printf("Pila desbordada");  

    }   
    else{//Agrega el CD a la pila
              ptrPila->cds[++(ptrPila->top)]=*ptrCD;
        printf("CD Agregado!!");

        printf("\nNombre del CD: %s",ptrCD->titulo);

    }
}
```

Comment: Quizá si agregaras la implementación completa o al menos un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que incluya un `main` con un ejemplo de cómo creas la pila e intentas agregar un elemento nos ayudarían a detectar cualquier otro problema que pudieras sufrir a parte del que te sugiero en mi respuesta.

Comment: ¿Algún avance? ¿Conseguiste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Todo apunta a que en ningún momento has inicializado los valores de la estructura `Pila` pasada a la función, en particular el valor de `top`.

Por ese motivo `top` puede tener un número aleatorio (posiblemente negativo, para que la llamada a `Full` te falle) que te esté forzando a escribir en una zona de memoria fuera del ámbito de tu programa.

Podrías inicializar el valor de dos maneras diferentes:

```
/* Definimos una pila con el valor "top" a cero */
Pila pila = { 0 };
/* También podríamos haberlo hecho así tras definirlo: */
pila.top = 0;
```

Ésta sería una prueba de concepto con el problema solucionado:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define tamanio 10

typedef struct{
    char titulo[50];
    char autor[50];
    float duracion;
    int numeroCan;
}CD;

typedef struct{
    int top;
    CD cds[tamanio];
}Pila;

/* Funcion para agregar un CD a la pila */
void Push(Pila *ptrPila, CD *ptrCD){
    if(ptrPila->top > tamanio){
        printf("Pila desbordada");
    } else { /* Agrega el CD a la pila */
        ptrPila->cds[++(ptrPila->top)]=*ptrCD;
        printf("CD Agregado!!");
        printf("\nNombre del CD: %s\n",ptrCD->titulo);
    }
}

int main() {
    /* Definimos el contenido de un CD */
    CD cd = { "Título", "Autor", 10.0, 5 };
    /* Definimos una pila con el valor "top" a cero */
    Pila pila = { 0 };
    /* También podríamos haberlo hecho así tras definirlo: */
    pila.top = 0;
    Push(&pila, &cd);
    return 0;
}
```

Su salida de `valgrind`:

```
$ valgrind ./pr 
==15904== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15904== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15904== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15904== Command: ./pr
==15904== 
CD Agregado!!
Nombre del CD: Título
==15904== 
==15904== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15904==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15904==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==15904== 
==15904== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15904== 
==15904== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15904== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Antes de solucionar el problema ésta era la salida de `valgrind`:

```
$ valgrind ./pr 
==15688== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15688== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15688== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15688== Command: ./pr
==15688== 
==15688== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==15688==    at 0x4005EC: Push (in /tmp/pr)
==15688==    by 0x4006AC: main (in /tmp/pr)
==15688== 
==15688== Invalid write of size 8
==15688==    at 0x4005EC: Push (in /tmp/pr)
==15688==    by 0x4006AC: main (in /tmp/pr)
==15688==  Address 0x120f648b60 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==15688== 
==15688== 
==15688== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==15688==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x120F648B60
==15688==    at 0x4005EC: Push (in /tmp/pr)
==15688==    by 0x4006AC: main (in /tmp/pr)
==15688==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==15688==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==15688==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==15688==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==15688==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==15688== 
==15688== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15688==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15688==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==15688== 
==15688== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15688== 
==15688== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15688== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==15688== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

En especial debes fijarte en los errores:

> ```
> ==15688== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==15688==    at 0x4005EC: Push (in /tmp/pr)
> ==15688==    by 0x4006AC: main (in /tmp/pr)
> ==15688== 
> ==15688== Invalid write of size 8
> ==15688==    at 0x4005EC: Push (in /tmp/pr)
> ==15688==    by 0x4006AC: main (in /tmp/pr)
> ==15688==  Address 0x120f648b60 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
> ```

Que te dicen que has hecho uso de un valor sin inicializar y que has escrito en una zona de memoria que no está en la pila, ni alojada ni liberada recientemente.

Comment: puede ser también un problema de gestión de memoria... ¿de dónde sale `tamanio`? ¿Qué valor tiene? ¿Y si el error está en el método `Full`? El problema de fondo es que la pregunta no está completa

Comment: Es cierto que podrían ser otros problemas. Probablemente la función `Full` sea correcta (exceptuando, quizá, la gestión de valores negativos de `top`). Si éste no fuera el error los siguientes candidatos serían que la pila la haya definido como puntero no la haya alojado en memoria y/o que haya usado `malloc` sin comprobar el valor de retorno, o que el valor del CD a insertar sufra exactamente los mismos problemas que podría sufrir la pila. Aún así, por experiencia, el error que tiene una probabilidad más alta de sufrir es el que describo en la respuesta. Gracias por el apunte.

Comment: Lo se, lo único que cuidado con las preguntas incompletas porque aquí votar positivo se vota poco.... pero la gente tiene las garras bastante afiladas cuando se trata de votar negativo :)

Comment: Te agradezco el consejo, a veces me los he llevado (con o sin razón) y los prefiero antes de dejar que caiga en el olvido una pregunta en la que podría ayudar.